# main Illegal State Exception

Tags: android, onclick, illegalstateexception

I cannot find the problem in my project. I open a menu with four buttons, they should bring user to other activities, but they dont. App crashes when you press any button.

Here is my menu class

```
package com.example.androidintermediate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    String activities[] = { "ACTIVITYMAIN", "SETTINGS", "INTERNALSTORE",
            "READING" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id = v.getId();
        for (int i = 0; i < activities.length; i++) {
            if (id == getResources().getIdentifier("b" + i, "id",
                    "com.example.androidintermediate")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.androidintermediate."
                        + activities[i]);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

LogCat

```
11-03 20:02:54.927: D/OpenGLRenderer(1384): Enabling debug mode 0
11-03 20:02:56.267: D/AndroidRuntime(1384): Shutting down VM
11-03 20:02:56.267: W/dalvikvm(1384): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6178908)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     ... 11 more
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.androidintermediate.ACTIVITYMAIN }
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     at com.example.androidintermediate.Menu.onClick(Menu.java:31)
11-03 20:02:56.271: E/AndroidRuntime(1384):     ... 14 more
11-03 20:02:58.603: I/Process(1384): Sending signal. PID: 1384 SIG: 9
```

The Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidintermediate"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITYMAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SETTINGS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".InternalStorage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INTERNALSTORAGE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Reading"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.READING" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Numbers"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NUMBERS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You are mixing up the component and action fields of the Intent.  Notice how action `android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITYMAIN"` in your manifest does not match `act=com.example.androidintermediate.ACTIVITYMAIN` in your error log

Comment: totally true. thanks you so much chris.

Answer (score 0):

You don't spell out the full package name when you create an intent.  Do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Menu.this, YourActivity.class);
```